# Week of Day for particular given date

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash-grok, grok

I have some date like 2019-07-03 10:25:43 I want a week of day for that date

I tried this but I got Thursday

```
%{YEAR:date_year}-%{MONTHNUM:date_month}-%{MONTHDAY:date_mday} %{HOUR:time_hour}:?%{MINUTE:time_minute}:?%{SECOND:time_second}
```

the actual output should be Wednesday for that date but it shows Thursday

Comment: `MONTHDAY` will simple parse `03` and store that in the `date_mday` field, which is correct. `03` doesn't mean it is a Wednesday, just that it is the 3rd day of the month.

Comment: I am not getting what you said,please come again

Comment: I think it's possible that 2019-07-03 is looking for March 7, 2019 (which is a Thursday) and not July 3, 2019. While your program looks to be processiing stuff in the right order (YY-MM-DD) you may wish to check what happens if you go to 2019-07-04 or 2019-07-02. If the day of the week moves 2 or 3 up or down, then your parsing statement has switched the month and day.